# How to sort cells in UITableView by Date in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to sort cells in ascending order by published date of the articles. I sorted by date array but I do not really now what to do next. As I understand I need to do that in cellforRow function.
Well, I am simply stuck. Help would be greatly appreciated.

p.s. I take info from one news api, if you need more code, just let me know

import UIKit
import WebKit

```
class WelcomeScreen: UITableViewController, NetworkManagerDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    
    var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    var posts = [Article]()
    


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ArticleViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        tableView.rowHeight = 130.0
        networkManager.delegate = self
        networkManager.fetchNews("us")
    
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return posts.count
    }

 
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! ArticleViewCell
        
               
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        
        
        cell.author.text = post.author ?? "N/A"
        cell.title.text = post.articleDescription
        cell.timePosted.text = dateFormatter.string(from: post.publishedAt)
        
        if let image = post.urlToImage{
        cell.imageForArticle.load(url: image)
        }
        let arrayOfDates = [post.publishedAt]
        
        let sortedDates = arrayOfDates.sorted(by: { $0.compare($1) == .orderedAscending })
        
        print(sortedDates)
        
    
        return cell
        
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let url = posts[indexPath.row].url else{
            fatalError()
        }
        let webVC = WebViewController(url: url, title: posts[indexPath.row].title)
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: webVC)
        navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(navVC, animated: true)
 

        }


    func didUpdateNews(root: Root) {
        posts = root.articles
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
        
    }

}

extension UIImageView {
    func load(url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Network Manager

```
import Foundation
```

protocol NetworkManagerDelegate{
func didUpdateNews(root: Root)
}
struct NetworkManager{
var delegate: NetworkManagerDelegate?

```
func fetchNews(_ countryCode: String) {
    var urlComponents = URLComponents()
    urlComponents.scheme = "https"
    urlComponents.host = "newsapi.org"
    urlComponents.path = "/v2/top-headlines"
    urlComponents.queryItems = [.init(name: "apiKey", value: "a16b15f863454928804e218705d0f019"),
                                .init(name:"country", value: countryCode)]
    
    if let url = urlComponents.url {
        performRequest(url)
    }
}

func performRequest(_ url: URL) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if error != nil{
            return
            
        }
        
        if let safedata = data {
            if let root = parseJson(data: safedata){
                delegate?.didUpdateNews(root: root)
            }
        }
        
        }.resume()
        
        
        func parseJson(data: Data) -> Root?{
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
            let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)

            
            
            
            return root
            
        }catch{
            print(error)
            return nil
}

        }
}
```

}

Comment: how can I format data without indexpath.row in my network manager?

Comment: `indexPath.row` is irrelevant to data, it's just a number that determines where in the list it will be displayed to the user. Whether a piece of data is displayed first in a list or last, it doesn't change the data and the data doesn't care where in the list it's displayed. Post the code for your network manager and show us how you're formatting data and what sort of formatting you want to achieve.

Comment: edited my post, added network manager at the bottom

Comment: " The order of the array determines the order of the cells in the table-view. ", thanks I got it, I wrote " posts = root.articles.sorted(by: { $0.publishedAt > $1.publishedAt })
" in my didUpdateNews func. It works as needed now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `cellForRowAt` table-view delegate function should only be used for taking finished data and injecting it into cells—that's it. You shouldn't instantiate things like date formatters in there or do anything other than injecting data into cells (with rare exceptions).

When you fetch the data from the network manager and the network manager returns data, do all of your parsing in there. This is where you should use the date formatter, for example. Once all of your data is parsed, sort the array by date and then call `tableView.reloadData()`. The key here is that the order of the array determines the order of the cells in the table-view.